# Laravel / Sql: How to join different table with condition

Tags: php, sql, laravel, join

I have an table A contain account_id and type

```
If type = 1 -> account_id will join with table User
If type = 2 -> account_id wwill join with table Customer
```

I have no idea how to write an SQL query?

Please help

Comment: Why not use PHP to decide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, you would write this with two `left join`s:

```
select a.*,
       coalesce(u.name, c.name) as name  -- how you access a field
from a left join
     users u
     on a.account_id = u.user_id and a.type = 1 left join
     customers c
     on a.account_id = c.customer_id and a.type = 2;
```